# Does appcache auto invalidate files not in manifest

Tags: html5-appcache

Let say on first version of manifest, we have file call abc.css . Subsequently, on second version of manifest, we remove abc.ss and append new file def.css . Does browser automatically invalidate abc.ss and remove from the caching list in browser upon second time user visited the website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Once files are cached using the app cache. They remain in cache, and the browser doesn't even *contact* the server to validate files or to see if any changes were made.

If you need to modify a file that is cached by the application cache, then you need to modify your manifest file.

From http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/

> You must modify the manifest file itself to inform the browser to refresh cached files.

Comment: can you elaborate more on the quote with example of old file abc.css and new file def.css inside manifest file?

Comment: I'm not  quite sure how I could elaborate more, so perhaps I'm just not understanding you. If you have `abc.css` set to be cached in the *manifest*, then any changes you do to `abc.css` will not be served, unless if the *manifest* file itself was modified. If you modified the manifest to remove `abc.css`, and added `def.css`, then that is a modification to the manifest file, thus it will stop caching `abc.css` and begin caching `def.css`.

Comment: Is just by changing commented version number inside manifest file, force all files inside manifest to be checked by browser ?

Comment: Yes, because that is a modification to the manifest file. Any modifications to the manifest file will cause the browser to check all cached resources .

Comment: With that being said, there is few "gotchas" with HTML5 appcache... like resources being cached by the browser through regular caching methods, and such. Since the appcache is an **additional** cache level, and not an alternative one. http://alistapart.com/article/application-cache-is-a-douchebag has a good list of appcache gotchas.